# JMeter and Regular Expression Extractor

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am using JMeter and responses have content like this, one per response.

```
<input name="_formkey" type="hidden" value="65aace0b-fa79-4b99-bf20-22c6ef2b043c" />
```

The value of _formkey has to be passed to the next request. I used regex extractor for this -

```
input name="_formkey" type="hidden" value="(.+?)"
```

This generates quite a few variables

```
formkey=bec48a21-3955-493e-93c2-97a1f0bf64cf
formkey_g=1
formkey_g0=input name="_formkey" type="hidden" value="bec48a21-3955-493e-93c2-97a1f0bf64cf" 
formkey_g1=bec48a21-3955-493e-93c2-97a1f0bf64cf
```

I am using formkey to pass the value and it is working fine. But how can I avoid the other 3 variables getting generated? Is my regex not 'well-formed" as in not doing a perfect job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is perfectly well formed. You are getting the number of groups and the groups themselves as the other variables. `formkey_g0` is the whole string that matches and `formkey_g1` is the part that matched within the parentheses. See [the examles](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#examples) on the JMeter page. To quote the relevant section for the purpose of completeness:

> For example, assume:
>
> - Reference Name: MYREF
> - Regex: name="(.+?)" value="(.+?)"
> - Template: $1$$2$
>
> The following variables would be set:
>
> - MYREF: file.namereadme.txt
> - MYREF_g0: name="file.name" value="readme.txt"
> - MYREF_g1: file.name
> - MYREF_g2: readme.txt
>
> These variables can be referred to later on in the JMeter test plan,
>   as ${MYREF}, ${MYREF_g1} etc

Note that `MYREF_g0` is always the complete match of the regex which is consistent with the use of regexes in Java and other programming languages.